# How to custom file formats work, encryption, packing etc

Tags: c++, encryption, dds

So say I take an example from Telltale games, they pack all their file assets into ttarch files, now I guess this is a custom file format that allows many file assets such as dds, jpg, bik, wav, 3ds etc to be packed into one file.

So someone has worked out how to explore these ttarch files and inside as you would imagine there are hundreds of files each with non standard file extensions(apart from the  lua files) such as d3dtx, d3dmesh, vers, spline, style, scene, there are also lua files which we all know.

The d3dtx files will be dds, jpg, bmp etc, so do you actually encrypt a dds file in this way, can someone enlighten me on the process of file encryption/packing files together?

Comment: There are quite a lot of games which simply use common archive formats like zip (easy to do because libraries are readily available) and give their files some cryptic extension so it's not blatantly obvious.

Comment: But these are not common.

Comment: So you are not asking about how people do this in general but about this one file format in particular? How does that help you as a game developer?

Comment: See also http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4389/writing-a-custom-model-file-format and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15134/how-to-create-a-game-save-file-format-in-c-using-stl and http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=custom+file+format

Comment: A file is just bits on the disk. You just write the bits you want (the images, sounds, et cetera) into a file in the order you want, probably with some bookkeeping information up front to tell you where you are going to put things for when you read them back later. It's a pretty broad topic in terms of the number of *different* ways to do things, but basically they are all variants of the same.

Comment: So it's just a raw binary dump with your own custom header and then you set a pointer to blocks, where each block is then fetched and decrypted according to your encryption algorithm?